# compact manifold is complete

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-verification, compact-manifolds

A smooth vector field $X$ on $M$ is complete if for each $t\in \mathbb{R}$ we have
$$\mathcal{D}_t = \{m\in M : t\in (a(m), b(m))\} = M,$$
where $(a(m),b(m))$ is the maximal interval of a integral curve $\sigma$ starting at $m$, that is

1. $0\in (a(m), b(m))$ and $\sigma(0) = m$
2. if $\gamma: (c,d) \rightarrow M$ is an integral curve of $X$ satisfies 1. above, then $(c,d)\subset (a(m), b(m))$ and $\gamma = \sigma|(c,d)$.

We can define a transformation $X_t$ with domain $\mathcal{D}_t$ by setting 
$X_t(m) = \sigma_m(t)$, and we have the following property: the domain of $X_s\circ X_t$ is contained in $\mathcal{D}_{s+t}$. If $s,t$ have the same sign, then the domain is $\mathcal{D}_{s+t}$ and $X_s\circ X_t = X_{s+t}$. I can also use the property that each $\mathcal D_t$ is open.

**My proof**: argue by contrapositive, suppose $\mathcal{D}_t \neq M$ for some $t\in \mathbb{R}$, then we show that  $\{\mathcal{D}_{t/n}\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is an open cover of $M$ and it has no finite sub covers.

First to show it is an open cover, for each $m\in M$, I can use the result that $(a(m), b(m))$ is a non empty open interval around zero (this is from the theory of ode), then $m\in \mathcal{D}_{t/n^*}$ for some large $n^*$.

To show it does not have any finite subcover, note that if $\mathcal{D}_{t/2} = M$, then the domain of $X_{t/2}\circ X_{t/2}$ is $M$, but at the same time, the domain is also $\mathcal{D}_{t/2 + t/2} = \mathcal{D}_t$ which is impossible. By this argument $\mathcal{D}_{t/n} \neq M$ for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Also since $\mathcal{D}_{t/n}$ is monotone increasing in $n$, so there can not be any finite subcovers.

Comment: Very strange way of stating the definition. Why not say that the $X$-flow for any initial condition can be defined for all $t\in\Bbb R$?

Comment: It is the definition in Warner's book. This is my first time studying this subject, I am not aware of any other definitions.

Comment: The definition in my comment is the one I've always known and taught. You should be able to see easily that they're equivalent.